# JAXB: How to convert Map to array-like format

Tags: java, json

Supposed I have:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>()
map.put("address1", "123 Main St");
map.put("address2", "456 Main St");
```

What's the adapter I can convert it to json in an array format like this?
    [  { "address1" : "123 Main St" } , { "address2" : "456 Main St" } , ....]

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a map?

What you could do is create a separate [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) for each string entry, and enter it into an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(new JSONObject().put("address1", "123 Main St").toString());
list.add(new JSONObject().put("address2", "456 Main St").toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! If I need to convert to xml format, this won't work. Is there a way to write an adapter to handle both xml and json format?

Comment: BTW, it doesn't matter if it's map. I basically just need a java object and its adapter that allows (un)marshalling to this array-like format

Comment: Yes, if you had to, I suppose you can write a wrapper with a boolean switch, one for xml and the other for json.

Comment: Clearly more work would be involved in writing xml (ie, name and depth of tags).